# Black Screen + Freeze after a couple minutes of gameplay (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, memory, graphics-card, freeze

Since this morning I'm getting random freezes after a couple of minutes of gameplay. It started with Battlefield 3, which made my screen turn black and I had to push the reset button since CTRL+ALT+DEL didn't work anymore. I also noticed that the power led on my monitor was blinking, which indicates that it doesn't get signal.

Anyway, I restarted the computer, put everything at stock settings (no overclock) and tried again. It happened a couple of more times in Battlefield 3, so in anger I blamed the game and uninstalled it. Then I went on to play Tomb Raider, same thing happened. I ran Aida64 for 30 minutes, Furmark for a short while and all without problems. It's just within games that it shuts down between like 10 seconds and 2 minutes after starting. I opened up the case, reseated my graphics card, switched places of my two memory sticks and hoped for the best. Same thing is happening.

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers for your graphic card and latest DirectX updates?